# PHPExcel: Parse spreadsheet data and store to database

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a workbook with tons of sheets. I want to iterate over each sheet and insert the row data into a MySQL database. Currently, my scripts inserts 1000 null rows into the database.

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("upload/".$workbook);

$cells = array();
$worksheetCount = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();
for($i=0; $i < $worksheetCount; $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($i);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10

    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5

    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {

      for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        $cells[] =  $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();           

      }

      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO players(player_name,Birthdate,Org,Level,Position,
                BT,Status,Service,League_Group_ID,Player_ID,Team_ID,NL_Position,
                NL_Slot,NL_SU_Order,AL_Position,AL_Slot,AL_SU_Order,SP_Order,RP_Order) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

            $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssss',$cells[0],$cells[1],$cells[2],$cells[3],$cells[4],$cells[5],
                $cells[6],$cells[7],$cells[8],$cells[9],$cells[10],$cells[11],$cells[12],$cells[13],$cells[14],
                $cells[15],$cells[16],$cells[17],$cells[18]);

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            reset($cells);

    }
}
```

?>

The headers in the spreadsheet match the columns in the database. What is wrong?

**Update** - just realized I should NOT being doing the SQL insert inside the column iterations so I corrected that however it is now inserting the header row 76 times into the database. (I have 76 rows in the spreadsheet.)

**Update 2:** - I had a reset() in there and it was not needed. Seems to be the cause of all my problems. It appears to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simplexlsx.class.php to parse the spreadsheet data and storing it in a database. Heres a article that shows how simple it is. [link](http://www.maskaravivek.com/php/simple-excel-uploader-in-php/)

Comment: I can explore that as an option but I'm also a little curious why this is not working.